# Displaying Categories sorting by custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, category, custom-attributes

How do I pull and display categories according to my custom field "Top_Menu"

```
$subCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->addFieldToFilter('Top_Menu', array('eq'=>'146'))
->load($category->getId())
->getChildren();
```

I keep getting this error

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::addFieldToFilter(Array
(
    [0] => Top_Menu
    [1] => Array
        (
            [eq] => 146
        )

)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need the category collection.

```
$catCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                         ->getCollection();
```

Once you have the collection you then need to apply your filters

```
$catCollection->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
```

This will give you all categories that have the "Top_Menu" Attribute value of '146'.
After you've applied all the filters you required, you can then either load your entire categories collection by calling $catCollection->load() or iterate through them using a foreach loop ( This will automatically call load()).

However if you want to print a multi level menu using all categories who's 'Top_Menu' value is '146' you need to use a bit of recursion. See example links

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660262/magento-programatically-build-category-tree
[enter link description here](http://www.justonestepsolutions.net/2012/09/get-all-categories-in-magento.html)

If you just apply the 'Top_Menu' filters to the collection then it should work

Comment: what if I only want a category of just one id?
$catCollection->addAttributeToFilter("Id" , array('eq' => 'xxxxx'));

Comment: If you just wanted one category with a particular id just use: Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($someID);

Comment: Can you tell me how to use it in addAttributeToFilter()?
Also how do I go about printing it on the screen?

Comment: $catCollection->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id" , array("eq" => $id));

Comment: How would you like it printed ?

Comment: I want to print a multi level menu of categories whose top_menu is = 146

Comment: can you only tell me how to pic up the name and the url after load?